# Deploy a BNA on a multi-node network which is running in SWARM (overlay)

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, docker-swarm, hyperledger-composer

The problem : We are trying to deploy a bna on a ***multi-node network*** which is running in **SWARM**.

We are using Hyperledger Composer to create a chaincode.

We have two VMs say VM1 and VM2
VM1 and VM2 are connected through ***SWARM both as managers***.
We have setup a Overlay swarm name called **my-net**

> VM1 has these docker containers all deployed on my-net
>    - orderer.example.com
>    - ca.example.com
>    - peer0.org1.example.com
>    - couchdb0
>
> VM2 has these docker container deployed on my-net
>    - peer1.org1.example.com
>    - couchdb1

Now our connection.json looks like this. Which is used to create PeerAdmin Card.

```
{
    "name": "hlfv1",
    "x-type": "hlfv1",
    "x-commitTimeout": 300,
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "client": {
        "organization": "Org1",
        "connection": {
            "timeout": {
                "peer": {
                    "endorser": "300",
                    "eventHub": "300",
                    "eventReg": "300"
                },
                "orderer": "300"
            }
        }
    },
    "channels": {
        "composerchannel": {
            "orderers": [
                "orderer.example.com"
            ],
            "peers": {
                "peer0.org1.example.com": {},
        "peer1.org1.example.com": {}
            }
        }
    },
    "organizations": {
        "Org1": {
            "mspid": "OrgMSP",
            "peers": [
                "peer0.org1.example.com",
        "peer1.org1.example.com"
            ],
            "certificateAuthorities": [
                "ca.example.com"
            ]
        }
    },
    "orderers": {
        "orderer.example.com": {
            "url": "grpc://<pee1IP>:7050"
        }
    },
    "peers": {
        "peer0.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "grpc://<pee1IP>:7051",
            "eventUrl": "grpc://<pee1IP>:7053"
        },
    "peer1.org1.example.com": {
            "url": "grpc://<pee2IP>:8051",
            "eventUrl": "grpc://<pee2IP>:8053"
        }
    },
    "certificateAuthorities": {
        "ca.example.com": {
            "url": "http://<pee1IP>:7054",
            "caName": "ca.example.com"
        }
    }
}
```

Well the whole thing works when we have single VM and we are able to successfully deploy the bna on the network
But when we add another VM to the my-net we are not able to install bna on the network

What we think is we are not able to put correct IP in the connection.json because of which we are failing.

Things to Note :
We are able to create channel on Peer0, and are able to join peer0 and peer1 both in the same channel successfully.
We do think it could be connection.json issue but we are not able to figure out the mistake.

This is the Error we see when installing the BNA

> Installing business network. This may take a minute... Error: Error
>   trying install business network. Error: No valid responses from any
>   peers. Response from attempted peer comms was an error: Error: 14
>   UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed

Comment: As per rocket chat - this error `Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: Connect Failed` usually comes back straight away with no significant delay, and it means that the client (presumably the `composer network install`) can't find the fabric servers (peers) at the addresses specified in the connection.json file - so this looks like a network resolution/routing error.

Comment: Running the docker in swarm mode requires few ports to be opened up. You can find those references here: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-configure-the-linux-firewall-for-docker-swarm-on-ubuntu-16-04 .

Answer (score 0):

I have been dealing with this kind of issues using docker swarm. To be able to have this kind of infra up and running using different host I am now using Rancher to manage the network communications between docker containers. Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the value of the channels to this:

```
"channels": {
    "composerchannel": {
        "orderers": [
            "orderer.example.com"
        ],
        "peers": {
            "peer0.org1.example.com": {
                "endorsingPeer": true,
                "chaincodeQuery": true,
                "eventSource": true
            },
            "peer1.org1.example.com": {
                "endorsingPeer": true,
                "chaincodeQuery": true,
                "eventSource": true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay applying this only identifies that how that peer can behave. Have you ever done a .bna deployment over swarm network, because what I understand the peer setting which you have portrayed are all default settings, which are already implied even when you are not using them.

Comment: Yes, the same as your setup, two peer nodes in one org using a docker swarm. What is the name of the channel that you've created?

Comment: Since you've successfully created a channel, it means that the network config is fine. It's really in the connection.json settings. Are you really sure that the port you're using is correct?